# UITableView memory bug

Tags: uitableview

I have a problem with memory leak in UITableView. If I'm at the bottom of  DetailViewController table and I want to go back to MasterViewController I have a crash. If I use UITableViewController, crash does not happen.

**AppDelegate**

```
_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
_window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
_window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[MasterViewController alloc] init]];
[_window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

**MasterViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
     DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

**DetailViewController**

```
@interface DetailViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    _tableView.rowHeight = 60;
    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 30;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"scrollViewDidScroll");
}

@end
```

Comment: If I set _table.view.delegate to nil in DetailViewController dealloc, bug was fixed. But I don't understand why it happens only if table at bottom.

Comment: Application tries to call scrollViewDidScroll:, but DetailViewController was deallocated. NSZombie helps to understand this.